# 1920s French uniform - Anyone know what kind of uniform?

Tags: uniform, versailles

Anyone know what kind of uniform this is? The picture was taken in Versailles around 1921, and it looks like his cap has a number on it - maybe 58?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bur anyway i am genially want to know the true !! :D

Comment: it looks more like 53 division soldier badge